# Flutter - ListView wrapped by GestureDetector, detector conflict

Tags: android, ios, flutter, listview

```
GestureDetector(
            onVerticalDragUpdate:  (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                    
                    double delta = details.delta.dy;

              
                  }
                ,
            onVerticalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {

            },
            child: Column(
                    child: Expanded(child:ListView.builder(physics: BouncingScrollPhysics())))
)
```

The listView can scroll itself. My requirement is : When the listview scroll to top, it's father widget GestureDetector (method: onVerticalDragUpdate) should be called. How to do?